# "TypeError" simple get method in python tornado to access record from Mongodb

Tags: python, json, mongodb, generator, tornado

Hi I have recently started programming in Python (I am newbie to python programming). I have a small collection of data in my MongoDB.I have written a simple get method to find all the data from my collection. But I have an error returning the fetched value.

Here is my code:

```
import bson
from bson import json_util
from bson.json_util import dumps

class TypeList(APIHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        doc = yield db.vtype.find_one()
        print(doc)
        a = self.write(json_util.dumps(doc))
        return a

    def options(self):
        pass
```

It gives me the fetched data.

But when I replace these lines

`a = self.write....
 return a`

with `return bson.json_util.dumps({ 'success': True, 'mycollectionKey': doc })`

it gives me a type error.

`TypeError: Expected None, got {'success': True, 'mycollectionKey': {'type': 1, 'item': 'cookie'}}`

Can anyone explain me why I get this error and is there anyway to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have referred the following solutions [Serializing MongoDB find()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024356/serializing-mongodb-find-return-into-non-anonymous-json-array-using-pymongo) and [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28963061/unable-to-serialize-json-object-from-mongodb-in-python) but it did not solve my problem

Comment: Do you mean return bson.json_util.dumps({ 'success': True, 'mycollectionKey': doc }) or return self.write(bson.json_util.dumps({ 'success': True, 'mycollectionKey': doc }))

Comment: **return bson.json_util.dumps({'success': True, 'mycollectionKey': doc})** this one gives me the type error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RequestHandler.get()` is not supposed to return anything. This error is simply warning you that you returned a value that is being ignored. Tornado handlers produce output by calling self.write(), not by returning a value.

Comment: Right now the output is sent as a string. Is there a way to send the output as a JSON object?

Comment: `RequestHandler.write` accepts dictionaries and will encode them as JSON.